# Android Studio's adb.exe (32 bit) has a very high CPU and power usage on Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

We are using Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 on Windows 10.  In fact, according to Windows Task Manager, Android Studio's power usage is so high (at constant 100% CPU usage) that a computer with 8 cores and 16GB becomes extremely slow and we almost cannot do anything on it.  This is a blocker and is preventing us to do any development work done.  We didn't have such an issue couple months ago with the previous Android Studio versions on the same system.  Has anyone else experienced a similar issue?

Comment: Have you tried to simply kill the adb process with high CPU usage?

Comment: @Robert Yes, but it immediately comes back up with the same effect.